# Finding ESP8266 in a network using android application (ionic vue)

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm working on project where my wemos d1 mini (with esp8266) is connected to wifi, and with asynchronous server, communicating with android app. At the moment I'm using static IP address for my server, but I want to make it universal (in case, if connected to other wifi network with different IP address range) so I need to find a way to get IP address of this server.
I have tried using mDNS, and it works great for browser, but not for android app.Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use a hostname instead?

Comment: isn't it the same thing as mDNS? or you mean to find IP address by hostname in router page?